# Send SMS from a service class on android

Tags: android

I am trying to send SMS from a service class and found the following code which sends SMS from Activity class. Getting an error on "this" in sendSMSMessage method which is quite understandable because the code for sending SMS from Activity class. How I can convert it to sending SMS from Service class? The Service class was written before, working without any issue in production. Trying to add this SMS sending code as an extra functionality.

```
protected void sendSMSMessage() {
    phoneNo = txtphoneNo.getText().toString();
    message = txtMessage.getText().toString();

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "SMS faild, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `this` with `getActivity()` and Voila!

Comment: Getting an error "Cannot resolve method getActivity() "